# C# SQL Server connection issues with many users - Degraded performance w/ Pooling

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, web

I've got an issue I'm hoping is a simple fix.

I have a C# web service that I interact with via JSON calling web methods that interact with a database (using the code below).

Connection string:

```
<add name="MainConnection" 
     connectionString="SERVER=10.218.147.71;DATABASE=******;UID=******-web;PWD=******;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=25;Max Pool Size=250;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Method code:

```
public List<MatchmakingSessions> GetMatchmakingSessionsWithSearchQuery(string mThisQuery = "") {
    List<MatchmakingSessions> matchmakingsessionsList = new List<MatchmakingSessions>();

    SqlConnection mConnection;
    SqlCommand mCommand;
    try {
        using (mConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnection"].ConnectionString)) {
            mCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [MatchmakingSessions] " + mThisQuery, mConnection);

            if (mConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
                mConnection.Open();
            }

            SqlDataReader mReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (mReader.Read()) {
                if (mReader.HasRows) {
                    MatchmakingSessions mMatchmakingSessions = new MatchmakingSessions();
                    mMatchmakingSessions.SessionID = (mReader["SessionID"] is DBNull) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(mReader["SessionID"].ToString());
                    //More DB calls to set properties...
                    matchmakingsessionsList.Add(mMatchmakingSessions);
                }
            }
            mReader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
        if (!GGErrorHandler.ContainsRegularTypes(x.Message)) {
            BusinessHelper.SendMailMessage(string.Format("<b>Error Message</b>: <br /><br />{0}</br><b>Stack Trace</b>: <br />{1}<br />", x.Message, x.StackTrace));
            throw new Exception(GGErrorHandler.GetUserFriendlyError("DefaultErrorMessage", ErrorSource.WebAPI, x.Message));
        }
        else
            throw new Exception(GGErrorHandler.GetUserFriendlyError(x.Message, ErrorSource.WebAPI, x.Message));
    }
    finally {
        mConnection.Close();
        mCommand.Dispose();
    }

    return matchmakingsessionsList;
}
```

I ran a stress test with only about 200 users calling the same method with about 1 second intervals per user, all users simultaneously and I started getting the error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

which eventually just crashed the entire web service.

Running `sp_who2` on the database I see around 250 connections. After running `iisreset` it drops to 40 connections. Then during the stress test, CPU on DB goes to 100%, and eventually leads to the issue above with timeouts. The web service also seems to suffer with high latency, and then eventual 500 errors on simple method interaction.

Am I totally off base with how I'm managing my connections?

Comment: Well, probably it is not your problem now, but a public WCF service that concatenates strings in that way is doomed from the start. Have you ever heard of Sql Injection?

Comment: The particular method above isn't a web method.  The web method that invokes this method is in-charge of creating the query; no user-input string is allowed into this query.

Comment: Have you profiled the query yet? Maybe there is excessive locking(blocking issues). Setup a SQL profile and run the stress test again. Collect performance counters and check that you are not peaking out the disk queue lengths and that query is properly indexed etc.

Comment: I did run a profiler, it has quite a few suggestions for indexes.  However, to side-step -- on the .NET Data Provider for SqlServer perf counters, the "NumberOfPooledConnections" on one box is currently at 8, and the "NumberOfFreeConnections" is at 0 -- either the counter is messed up, or connections aren't getting released back into the pool, or I'm not reading it right?

Comment: Well.. to go a little further, was watching these counters as I did a stress test with 500 users and I saw the NumberOfPooledConnections jump up to 50 (which is what I had the max set to in this connection string), and then shortly after it would drop back down to around 5, slowly.. ( I have min set to 0 ).. so, based on this it seems it would be working (and also explain my mistake above with why there are no free connections.. since min is set to 0, duh -- lol)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and dispose of the mReader.  Technically when it goes out of scope it should drop, but funnier things have happened. (mReader.Dispose();)

Comment: As Steve noted, you should not run your queries that way.  At the very least make the query include a parameter and then send (add) the parameter.  It will protect you to a small degree.

Comment: Tried wrapping the reader in a using block; closing it; disposing of it; as well as the command itself.  Didn't seem to make any difference.  I'm trying to setup SQLDependency caching now, but not having much luck -- so I suppose just going to create a cache object based on the query and invalidate the cache when one of the other web service methods updates the table (even though it would be so much more awesome if the triggers would work correctly -- not sure why the built in SQL dependency isn't working).

Comment: But, back on topic -- does assigning a parameter within the query make the SQL Client or SQL itself do any pre-processing of the param that is being sent?  Since I use that to specify conditionals within the WHERE and also applying ORDER BY statements, or even INNER JOINs -- would it not just be the same as concatenating the string in the command before sending to SQL?

Comment: Yes.  You will at least limit it to a likely limit.  Things like command terminators, etc. will most likely not be allowed to go through.   On a side not - which I don't particularly recommend, you can run the garbage collector every bit to see if it helps clear things up - but you will still need to get to the bottom of the actual problem (GC.Collect).

Comment: I suspect the issue is that when multiple thousands of clients on a stress testing calling multiple methods per second that all need a DB connection, I'm actually running over the pool max limit -- how would I go about properly scaling this issue to have multiple pools?  Should I create another website/app pool to load balance further?  Do I need additional web servers?

Comment: I have taken your advice to heart for one of our internal apps and used the following document to optimize the app pool in question paying particular attention to the virtual memory usage and number of worker threads.  The article is IIS 7, but have applied some of successfully on IIS6.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx